# A Hausdorff $ k$-space is minimal $ KC$ if and only if it is compact.

Tags: general-topology

> Atopological space is called $k$ - space if it has the property that any subset $S$ such that $ S \cap K $ is closed for all closed compact $ K $ is itself closed.
>
> The bellow theorem comes from " THE FDS-PROPERTY AND SPACES IN WHICH COMPACT SETS ARE
>   CLOSED." I have some problem with this theorem.
>
> ****Theorem:****A Hausdorff $k$-space is minimal $ KC$ if and only if it is compact.
>
> **Proof:** The sufficiency is clear. For the necessity, let $(X, τ)$ be a non-compact space which
>   satisfies the hypothesis of the theorem. Define a new topology σ on X as follows:
>   $σ = \{U ∈ τ : a \not\in U \} ∪ \{U ∈ τ : a ∈ U , \quad   \text{X - U is   compact} \}$.
>   Clearly (X, σ) is a compact and σ ⊂ τ. we claim that
>   $(X, σ)$ is a $KC$-space.To this end, suppose that $ S ⊆ X$ is a compact subset
>   of $(X, σ)$. It is clear that $cl_{σ}(S) ⊆ cl_{τ} (S) ∪ \{a\}$ . There
>   are then two possibilities: If $S$ is a compact subset of $(X, σ)$ and
>
> **(a)** if $a \not\in S$, then then by the preceding remarks, S is compact, and hence closed, in $(X, τ)$
>   and so $X - S $ is an open $σ$-neighbourhood of a. Thus $a \not\in cl_{σ}(S)$ and so $cl_{σ}(S) = cl_{τ} (S) = S$. then $cl_{σ}(S) = cl_{τ}
> (S) $.
>
> **(b)**: If on the other hand, $a ∈ S$, then $cl_{σ}(S) = cl_{τ}
> (S)$
>
> and so if $S$
>   is not closed in $(X, σ)$, then it is not closed in $ (X, τ)$ either. Since $(X, τ)$ is a $k$-space,
>   there is some compact set $C$ in $ (X, τ) $ such that $ C ∩ S $ is not closed in $ C$. Furthermore,
>   if the chosen compact set $ C $ has the property that $a ∈ C$, then since $(X, τ)$ is Hausdorff,
>   given $x ∈ cl_{τ} (C ∩ S) - (C ∩ S)$, we can find disjoint open neighbourhoods $ U, V $ of $x$ and $a$
>   respectively. Then
>
> $ C - V$ is a compact subset of $(X, τ)$ with the property that 
>   $S ∩ (C - V ) $ is not closed in $ C - V $. Hence we have shown that it is
>   possible to choose$ C$ so that  $a \not\in C $.
>
> Then  $cl_{τ} (C ∩ S) ⊆ C $ is a closed, hence compact subset of $ (X, τ) $ which does not contain $ a$
>   and hence is also closed in $ (X, σ)$ . Thus $T = S ∩ cl_{τ} (C ∩ S)$ is a $σ$-closed subset of $S$ and
>   hence is compact in $(X, σ)$. However, since $a \not\in T$ , it follows that $T_{τ} = T_{σ}$ and hence $T$ is
>   compact in $(X, τ)$, a contradiction, since $x ∈ cl_{τ} (T ) - T$ .
>
> **But:**
>
> **can you explain that : why he said that "**
>
> **(1)**:$ C - V$ is a compact subset of $(X, τ)$ with the property that $S ∩ (C - V )
> $ is not closed in $ C - V $ . Hence we have shown that it is possible to choose $ C$ so that  $a \not\in C $.
>
> **(2)**: why $cl_{τ} (C ∩ S) ⊆ C $ is a closed?
>
> **(3)** :$(X, τ)$ is $ T_{1}$, is it right to say that  $(X, σ)$ is $ T_{1}$?
>
> Thanks.

Comment: Again you have made [suggested edit](http://math.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/87290) from a different account. Sorry for saying this again and again, but registering and merging all your accounts would make things easier for you. (In this particular case you were not able to edit your own post.)

Answer (score 2):

(A point you forgot to mention: $a \in X$ is just any (now fixed) point of $X$)

Point (3) is easiest to handle: Suppose $(X,\tau)$ is $T_1$; this is equivalent to the fact that all sets of the form $X \setminus \{x\}$ are in $\tau$. If $x \neq a$, then $X \setminus \{x\}$ contains $a$, and so is in $\sigma$ because its complement is $\{x\}$ which is compact (second part of the union defining $\sigma$). If $x = a$ then $X \setminus \{a\}$ is in $\tau$ and does not contain $a$ and so is in $\sigma$ because of the first part of that union. In all cases, all sets of the form $X \setminus \{x\}$ are also in $\sigma$, and so $(X, \sigma)$ is $T_1$ whenever $(X, \tau)$ is.

As to (1): In the proof, we have a compact (under $\sigma$) compact set $S$, that we assume is not closed in $(X,\sigma)$. We then know we can assume $a \in S$ (as the case $a \notin S$ was already handled) and in that case we know that $S$ has the same closure under both $\sigma$ and $\tau$ and so $S$ is also not closed in $(x, \tau)$.

We then apply that $(X, \tau)$ is a k-space to get a compact $C$ (in $(X,\tau)$, so $C$ is also closed there as this space is Hausdorff) with $S \cap C$ *not* closed in $C$, under the relative topology induced by $(X, \tau)$, of course.

The authors want this $C$ to have the property that $a \notin C$ as well (for the rest of the proof to work) so they show that *if* $a \in C$ (contrary to what they'd like) we can choose a new, smaller $C$ that does have the property, and this new $C$ is of the form $C \setminus V$, for the $C$ we start with and a neighbourhood $V$ of $a$, as shown in the proof.

Then in the remainder they assume that the $C$ (compact in $\tau$ and such that $S \cap C$ is not closed in $C$ under its $\tau$-topology) indeed has the property that $a \notin C$.

This is the reason of the remark "Hence we have shown that it is possible to choose $C$ so that $a \notin C$".

Then (2) follows: the sentence in the paper is: "Then $\operatorname{cl}_{\tau}(S \cap C) \subset C$ is a closed, hence compact subset of $(X, \tau)$, which does not contain $a$ and hence is also closed in $(X, \sigma)$".

Well, $\operatorname{cl}_{\tau}(S \cap C)$ is by definition closed in $(X, \tau)$, as it is the closure of a set, in this case $S \cap C$! It is a subset of $C$ because $C$ is already closed in $(X, \tau)$ (recall it is a compact set in a Hausdorff space), and the closure of $S \cap C$ under $\tau$ is the smallest $\tau$-closed set containing it (and $C$ is one of those closed sets). And it is in $\sigma$, because of the first part of the definition of $\sigma$: all $\tau$-open sets that do not contain $a$ are in $\sigma$ as well. And as $\operatorname{cl}_{\tau}(S \cap C)$ is a closed subset of the $\tau$-compact set $C$, it is also compact (under $\tau$, and hence under $\sigma$ as well, as it is coarser). Here we use the fact that $C$ (and its subsets) miss $a$, as we could assume from above.